# Multiple Applications access one single xml file at same time using c#

Tags: c#

I am facing problem with "Access one xml file from 2 different applications at same time".
But it shows error code is "access denied, because another process using the file".
I applied all lock methods, but no use (same error).

Comment: Please post the sample code here.

Comment: Please add details around how you're trying to access the file and where you're receiving the exception.

Comment: That's just a really bad idea. Write a server application that deals with the file , have the other two apps use it. Course you could basically end up writing your own DBMS, which is a tad silly.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the correct `FileShare` enumeration value when instantiating the underlying `FileStream` allows you to control this.

Ref.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx

Comment: How can I write a FILESHARE property in XDocument in XML File

Comment: XDocument.Load and .Save have overloads which allow you to use your own Stream with the correct FileShare property.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply......And Can you provide a code with Xdocument and File sharing property.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it would be possible for two applications to write to the same file at the same time, the file would be corrupted. I recommend you to use a database instead.